# Helpful flags were raised in my name

Tags: support, flags

I'm 100% sure I haven't raised these helpful flags that were attributed to me. I don't have an autoreporting script running. What happened here?

[image: flags raised in my name]

Answer (score 102, accepted):

###### You authorized Charcoal to raise spam flags using your account.

These flags were raised by the [Charcoal project](https://charcoal-se.org/) via [metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/), based on the posts being reported by [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/). You have an account on metasmoke under the name "the4kman", which [you created at 2017-09-11 15:07Z](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=39938010#39938010). At some time after that, you authorized metasmoke to use flags on your account to automatically flag spam. Automatic flags are randomly allocated to users who have granted authorization for their flags to be used. [Here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging/users/321/logs) you can find a list of the automatic flags which metasmoke has raised under your account.

###### Spam volume has been 100 times higher than normal over the last couple days.

Under normal conditions, there are not all that many autoflags raised in a short period of time, particularly from one user. Unfortunately, the network has been experiencing a large volume of "support number" spam over the last several days, primarily on Stack Overflow, but also on other sites in the Stack Exchange Network. There were 596 automatic flags placed by metasmoke in the last 24 hours, and that's with metasmoke being down and not raising *any* flags for about 12 of those 24 hours. That volume of automatic flags is between 10 to 50+ times as many as are normally raised in a single day (so, about 100 times as much spam in the last day as we normally see). Thus, it's not all that surprising that you see a couple using your account.

###### If you don't want autoflags raised on your behalf, you can de-authorize metasmoke's use of your flags at any time.

If you don't want metasmoke to use your account to raise automatic flags, there are two ways for you to remove your authorization for your flags to be used:

- ###### From metasmoke

  Log into metasmoke. Go to [this page](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging/preferences), and uncheck "Allow metasmoke to raise flags for my account".
- ###### From your profile pages on Stack Overflow

  Go to [the "Applications" page (under "Site Settings") in your Stack Overflow profile's "Settings" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/apps/3151675). Click on "Remove" for the "Metasmoke Autoflagger" application to remove the *write* authorization for metasmoke to use your account for flagging via the SE API. If you want, you can also "Remove" the authorization for the "metasmoke" application, but that's just metasmoke's *read* authorization to verify your identity. It's not the *write* authorization for autoflagging.
  [Note: there's [a bug in the Stack Exchange profile "Applications" page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370293/removing-granted-access-to-an-application-is-no-longer-working), so you may need to follow the instructions in my comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370293/removing-granted-access-to-an-application-is-no-longer-working#comment1235805_370293) in order to be able to use the "Remove" buttons.]

###### Getting more information about Charcoal, metasmoke, SmokeDetector, and autoflags

- There's an **[Introduction to Participating in Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/training/index)**, which provides a good overview.
- There are [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) and [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/) wiki pages with more detailed information.
- There are multiple posts on Meta Stack Exchange which have discussed spam, SmokeDetector, metasmoke, and autoflagging. A few of them are:

  - "[Can a machine be taught to flag spam automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/271271)"
  - "[A machine can flag spam automatically. Can it do better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307585/271271)"
  - "[2016: a year in spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289817/271271)"
  - "[2017: a year in spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305338/271271)"
  - "[2018: a year in spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321346/271271)"
  - Related: "[How accurate are users with their spam flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307717/271271)"

Comment: FWIW, he's flagged 19 times in the last year, with only 5 of those being on SO, and 3 of them being in the last week or so

Comment: Why can't the smokedetector not flag posts under his own name? Would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: @Trilarion that wouldn't work. SD is a single account and that would pose a hard limit of (at most) 100 flags/day. That's why you can sign up to "lend ha hand" to SD with *your own* flags.

Comment: @Trilarion in fact, [SD has also participated in some of the flagging](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging/users/-1/logs). Also, for this specific spam wave, the post was automatically flagged by a few users to fasten the clean-up. SD alone can only flag once per post.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Maybe somebody could raise that hard limit for SD?

Comment: @AndrewT. Maybe SD could flag more than once per post? After all "flagged by a few users to fasten the clean-up" when users aren't even aware that they are doing it, is a bit fishy.

Comment: @Trilarion nope, even if used by an automated program it's a normal account subject to normal SO rules that apply to everyone. Changing the rules to give more power to some account for any reason is not a good idea at all.

Comment: @Trilarion SD does flag under its own name, but, as already mentioned, flags for any user is limited to, between 10 to, at most, 100 post flags a day on any one site, and a single active flag on any post. The goal is to get spam posts deleted quickly, even without moderator intervention. On some sites, moderators aren't present for extended periods of time. I've even had spam flags *expire* on some sites. So, with autoflagging we want to raise more than one flag per post. How many flags metasmoke raises depends on how confident, based on historical accuracy, it is that the post is spam.

Comment: @Trilarion the user already has to register to metasmoke and [consciously grant the authorization to participate in autoflagging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ythBV.png). It's an opt-in option.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli "Changing the rules to give more power to some account for any reason is not a good idea at all." You mean hijacking user accounts and let them operate like a bot network to achieve the same goal is a better idea? I think that being transparent is the better approach. Obviously, SD is so powerful that is needs more power than what normal users get and IMHO should have it.

Comment: @AndrewT. "...consciously grant the authorization to participate in autoflagging...." That part is clear. The OP here probably just forgot about it. But then I wonder if the TOS of SO allow conscious autoflagging. After all it's not supervised. SD could flag anything. And since the user didn't actually consciously perform these actions, it's even resembling a bit some kind of fraud. Why not simply grant the authorization to autoflag to SD directly?

Comment: @Trilarion in what way SD is not being transparent? As already highlighted multiple times in the above post and comments you have to (1) register to SD (2) authorize it to use your account (3) create a custom rule for auto-flagging and approve it. Everything is explained in detail ad nauseam. Come on... - As per why SO lets the community do such an essential task and doesn't have their own decent spam bots active, well that's another question. Giving extra power to a bot account does not solve the issue and creates a very bad precedent for the future.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli It's not transparent in the way that to the system it appears as if a user had flagged something while in truth a bot somewhere did the work instead. Come on... if you cannot see the problems here, I don't know how else to describe them.

Comment: @Trilarion *hijacking user accounts and let them operate like a bot network to achieve the same goal is a better idea?* - there is no hijacking of any sort, as it's all consensual. It is transparent as you can clearly see from SD when it used your account to flag. The SO flagging system is designed as is, and yes this unfortunately right now is the best way the community has to help with spam. It appears as flagged by the user itself because again that's what you sign up for, and is very clearly explained in a big red notice when you do (see Andew's comment above).

Comment: @Trilarion example of what I mean by "you can clearly see from SD when it used your account to flag": https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjuIn.png - in my case I also tailored the auto-flagging settings to my liking to achieve 100% accuracy based on existing SD history.

Comment: @Trilarion If you don't like having your account used by a bot, you don't sign up for it. It's as simple as that. I can't see what's bugging you about it.

Comment: @nobody the problem is that the bot needs other accounts to function. If SO the company would recognize the contribution of the bot and accomodate it accordingly then this whole setup of users appearing to raise flags while they have never done so would not be necessary.

Comment: @Trilarion there is so much thing on how SD and metasmoke work, to ensure the accuracy of autoflagging, and preventing flag mistakes that I'm not sure if the comment thread may fit... feel free to register to metasmoke and see how it works, or create a meta post to give SD more power, or join the chat room [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) for more inquiry.

Comment: @Trilarion Charcoal has gone through *multiple* rounds of open discussion about autoflagging on Meta Stack Exchange. Stack Overflow, the company, is *fully* aware of its existence and has actively aided in allowing SD to operate (e.g. granting SD a larger quota than normal on the SE API). The way that it is currently set up (i.e. using the accounts of users who have granted that permission) is the solution which was decided upon based on discussions with both the community and with the company. Is it the best possible way? No. Is it the way that can  work without major development by SE? Yes.

Comment: @Makyen In other words, it's a known problematic solution, but it's a workable and approved solution that was able to be implemented using the developer resources currently available for it.

Comment: @Makyen is there any indication between an autoflag and a normal flag? Can one earn the Deputy and Marshal badges based on autoflags alone?

Comment: @NearHuscarl No, there isn't, directly on SE, a clear indication between an autoflag and a normal flag. Moderators can see a bit of a difference by looking at the grouping of users who flagged the post. It is, however, possible to explicitly determine based on the record on metasmoke as to which flags raised through metasmoke were autoflags and which were manually raised.

Comment: @NearHuscarl Yes, it is possible to get those badges from autoflags alone. However, the number of autoflags which are actually assigned to each individual is low on a per site basis, so it would take multiple years. I haven't checked, but it's unlikely that anyone has gotten those badges *just* from autoflags. Most participants in Charcoal get the bulk of their flags by watching reports come in and manually evaluating the post and flagging when appropriate.